# How to understand "in comparison to which"

Tags: pronouns

> The space travels described in science fiction stories always used to be epic adventures, in comparison to which current journeys in space seem quite mundane.

I think that the correct order is that "in comparison to that the space travels described in science fiction stories always used to be epic adventures, current journeys in space seem quite mundane."

What is the function of the "which" in the original sentence? Could you give me some other examples like that?

Comment: The "in comparison to which..." is a bit clunky. You could say "by comparison..." The role of 'which' in the quoted sentence can be misuderstood on the first reading, seeming to be "which current journeys" but as the next comment says, it is not.

Comment: _which_ here refers to "_The space travels described in science fiction stories_".

Comment: Your version has the word 'that' in the wrong place. Try "In comparison to the space travels described in science fiction stories **that** always used to be epic adventures."

Comment: I'm not sure that 'space travel' has been countified; I'd certainly use 'The examples of space travel in ...' or 'The space operas ...'.